# convergence of a series involving $\cosh$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have a question regarding infinite series. Is it true that
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \cosh{\left(\frac{1}{3}\gamma^3x_i\right)}\underset{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow 1
\end{equation}
if and only if
\begin{equation}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \vert x_i\vert \underset{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow 0,\end{equation}
where $\gamma >0$ is a constant, and $\sup_i \vert x_i \vert < \infty$.

Any ideas (a proof?)??? Every help/hint is really much appreciated!

many thanks!

Comment: That $\gamma^3/3$ there by the way is really irrelevant to the problem. You could just as well assume that it's $1$. It would simplify the expressions (I don't think it helps much though, it's just an opinion)!

Comment: yes, I agree. I just stated the problem in the way that I encountered it. as it turns out (see below), it is really irrelevant. thanks for looking at it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\alpha = \gamma^3/3$.  The following inequality holds for the convex function $x \mapsto \cosh(\alpha x)$:

$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\cosh(\alpha x_k)}{n} = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\cosh(\alpha |x_k|)}{n}\geq  \cosh \left(\alpha \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{|x_k|}{n}\right) \geq 1.
$$

(The mean of some function values is at least the function value of the mean.)  If the first term converges to $1$ then so does the last $\cosh$ term.  This shows that $$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{|x_k|}{n}$$ converges to $0$. If $|x| \leq N$ then $$\cosh(\alpha x) \leq 1 + |x| \frac{\cosh(\alpha N) - 1}{N}.$$  The reverse implication follows directly from this inequality since $|x_k| \leq N$ for some bound $N$ and all indices $k$.

Comment: thank you so much, that's a great proof! I really appreciate your support in this!